# Is there a way to turn off LinkedIn verifier code?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I implemented LinkedIn sign in via oauth2.0 to get user profile, name and email

But I have a problem after user enters email and password - the popup from LinkedIn gives a message - "Please enter the following verifier on the app"

Is there a way how to bypass that or where exactly I need to enter the code?

Comment: did you set all params for oauth callback correctly?

Comment: can you provide code sample that you used to authorize LinkedIn app?